# Is there a tool for MySQL schema mapping & sync.?

Tags: php, mysql, command-line-interface

I'm trying to improve my workflow handling MySQL schemas and migrations. When I'm starting a project from scratch (with PHP, most of the times), I find myself changing my DB schema all the time. I mean: you forgot a field here and there, or you want to remove an unused field.

I was reading a lot about some ORMs, but they seem to add lots of functionality that I don't really need. Overhead is not an option.

So, I was "dreaming" with this, but I don't know if exists, or if it's even possible:

- Write schemas with YAML like:

  ```
  Table:Posts
    id:int
    title:varchar(500)
    content:text
  ```
- Run a cli command that generates schema

  ```
  $ schema update
  ```
- Make changes to your yaml (ex. add a field):

  ```
  Table:Posts
    id:int
    title:varchar(500)
    content:text
    published:datetime
  ```
- Run cli command again and only ADD COLUMN (doesn't regenerate the whole thing)

  ```
  $ schema update
  ```

Is it possible? Is there a tool like that? I can write SQL, I can write migrations, but I think it would be awesome a tool that "recognizes changes" on my definition, and automatically sync the DB.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think traditional migrations and a healthy portion of care is better. Synching is a complex topic and leaves you little control over complex migrations.

Comment: Maybe. But MySQL WorkBench has a super-mega-cluttered visual interface for doing this. You update your model, hit synchronize, and it takes care of generating the SQL code to set your DB up to date. I wish there was something even simpler.

Comment: @fedeisas: I agree with you re MySQL Workbench, but I've been rather enjoying a very nice Mac alternative: [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/).  Not quite the answer you were after, but if you're on a Mac perhaps something worth considering?  Or, if you make your schema changes in a development database, you could consider [Schema Sync](http://schemasync.org/)?

Comment: @eggyal +1 for Schema Sync. I think I'm gonna make a script that recreates my SQL Create statements from my YAML definition, then uses Schema Sync to compare current CREATE with the new CREATE, and write SQL migrations in a folder.